# Traces of gamma matrices in $d$ dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace, clifford-algebra

For $d=4$, some identities of the traces of gamma matrices are:

- $tr[\gamma_\mu] = 0$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu ] = 4g_{\mu\nu}$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu\gamma_\alpha\gamma_\nu] = 0$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu\gamma_\alpha\gamma_\nu\gamma_\beta] =4\left(g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta} - g_{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta} + g_{\mu\beta}g_{\alpha\nu}\right) $

Can someone confirm if the generalization of the above to $d$ dimensions is:

- $tr[\gamma_\mu] = 0$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu ] = dg_{\mu\nu}$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu\gamma_\alpha\gamma_\nu] = 0$
- $tr[\gamma_\mu\gamma_\alpha\gamma_\nu\gamma_\beta] =d\left(g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta} - g_{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta} + g_{\mu\beta}g_{\alpha\nu}\right) $

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices#Identities).

Comment: "change the overall factor of 4 to $tr[I_N]$". So it is correct! Thank you!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Actually, in my particular case it still will be d=4. Giving some context: i'm using dimensional regularisation to work out the quark loop which means I'll have traces of gamma matrices, however these traces are over the spin indices which have nothing to do with spacetime dimensions, since quarks are still 4-spinors in any d. Do you agree?

Comment: Dimensional regularization has well established rules and subtleties. But spinor components do very much vary with dimension.... peruse the WP article cited...

Comment: $N$ is not $d$. You need $N=2^{\lfloor d\rfloor}$.